# Rewrite java 8 method with Lightweight-Stream-API for using for api 21

Tags: java, android, lightweight-stream-api

I don't know all capabilities of Stream API.

I have an `AutoCompleteTextView` with custom adaptor,I made a method that know if entered data in `AutoCompleteTextView` is from suggested data or not ,
[image: Call requires API level 24 (current min is 21) Error]

Now I want rewrite it using [Lightweight-Stream-API](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API) for using under api 24

method in java8

```
 private boolean isFromSuggestedData(List<StoreCategory> list, final String nameEnglish){
   return list.stream().anyMatch(item -> nameEnglish.equals(item.getNameEnglish()));
}
```

Comment: The [test for `anyMatch`](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API/blob/master/stream/src/test/java/com/annimon/stream/streamtests/AnyMatchTest.java) looks like the `java.util.stream` one. Just try changing the `import`s ans stream creation as such.

Comment: thanks, @naman this made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use kotlin "any" function

```
private fun isFormSuggestedData(list: List<StoreCategory>, nameEnglish: String): Boolean = list.any { nameEnglish == it.nameEnglish }
```